# Run Karma test suite against multiple versions of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I help maintain a library that depends on jQuery, and I'd like to automate the process of running our tests against each jQuery version we support.

Does anybody know of a method to run a Karma test suite against multiple versions of jQuery?